# Transit visa for Turkey

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, transit-visas, turkey

I will be travelling to Canada (from Bangladesh) on December through Istanbul. In the online e-visa page for transit visa, i could only find USA, Shengen countries, Ireland and UK. Does that mean I will not be granted an online Visa?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: I am a Bangladeshi citizen

Answer (score 1):

If you want/need to enter Turkey (for example to pick up luggage - this is if the trip is **not** in one booking - or to see Istanbul for a while), you will need a transit visa from a Turkish embassy.

Otherwise you need no visa at all.

You can apply for an e-visa and get it, by marking all the checkboxes, but if you don't actually fulfil the requirements, it will be invalid.

But like I said, if you just transit there and your trip is in a single booking, you do **not** need a visa

Comment: @Sid If this answer satisfies you, please upvote and accept it by pressing the up arrow and the button below the down arrow